# How to get current_user in Rails 5 API with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an Angular 2 app that is using a Rails 5 API to create projects (think posts). I'm trying to add the current_user id to a new project (see the attempt in the Projects controller) when created but I get NoMethodError (undefined method `projects' for nil:NilClass): app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:18:in`create'. Line 18 is the line that attempts to use current_user when creating the project. If I remove current user and make it Project.new or if I hard code the user_is on the client side, there are no issues but with many users, this would be a problem. In the end, I want to know how to get the current user id and insert it when creating the project.

Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken

  def current_user
    @current_user
  end

end
```

Projects Controller

```
def create
  @project = current_user.projects.new(project_params)

  if @project.save
    render :show, status: :created, location: @project
  else
    render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Comment: http://zacstewart.com/2015/05/14/using-json-web-tokens-to-authenticate-javascript-front-ends-on-rails.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Issue was than angular2-token wasn't passing correct headers for subsequent requests to non-auth routes such as my projects routes. current_user is good to go now.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, how did you add the correct headers using angular2-token?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you haven't called the `authenticate_user!` method that sets the `current_user`.

Perhaps try making your `ApplicationController` look something like this...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken

  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

The `before_action` call here ensures that the `current_user` method returns a value.

Comment: Doesn't hit the mark. Simple throws a 401 as below:                    Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"email"=>"jim@iss.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "session"=>{"email"=>"jim@iss.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (0.19ms)
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 5ms (Views: 3.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)